# Input Array - Multiple arrays provided given specific bounds

Tags: python, arrays, input

I am trying to create python code which will allow the user to enter an initial amount of arrays and then let them fill the amount of arrays they want.

**Example**

x = 10 arrays (given arrays)

[0, 0, 0, 0]
...
[0, 0, 0, 0]

Up to ten arrays. I'm trying to keep it within 10 elements per array (limit) and keep having trouble trying to find the best way to implement this. I've have tried using for loops and have gotten nowhere. Is there any better way to do this? Would anyone be able to provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this?

```
n = int(input("length of list: "))
l = []
for i in range(n):
    l.append(int(input()))
print(l)
```

Comment: I'm looking for something similar. When the user enters the initial input I need that to refer to the amount of arrays and then the second aspect (for loop) will populate each array with the characters up to a maximum of 10 for each.